# need to know the use of rm -f in unix and how to implement in dos

Tags: windows, unix, shell, command-line

```
rm -f /obi/u01/informatica/v711/pmserver/SrcFiles/coe/aone/AccessOne_Daily_Input.xml
```

What is its use in unix and its possible implementation in dos?

Comment: It is NOT DOS. `cmd.exe` is a native Windows application.

Comment: Maybe the OP still uses DOS. There definitely *were* questions specific to DOS.

Comment: Well, it was originally tagged "windows".

Answer (score 18):

It just forces a file to be deleted, even if it's read-only.

```
del /f filename
```

is the rough equivalent in Windows command shells.

Comment: Much as I hate voting up Jon, he's exactly right. +1.

Comment: Every vote you get, brings you 10 points closer to integer overflow :-D

Comment: Luckily one can safely upvote him here, as he isn't nearly close to overflowing :-)

Answer (score 1):

`rm -f <filename>` deletes `<filename>` if it exists, even if it is read-only to the current user. If `<filename>` does not exist, `rm -f <filename>` silently returns success. If attempting to delete `<filename>` results in a permissions error or `<filename>` is a directory, `rm` will exit with an error message. See [POSIX.1-2008 Shell & Utilities: rm](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rm.html).

This is useful in one-off situations where you want to ensure that a particular file does not exist. `rm -f` will silently succeed if the file doesn’t exist; it will attempt to even remove a read-only file if it already exists. It saves you from having to check that the file exists first or enabling the file’s write permission bit. This makes it very useful in a [Makefile](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html)’s conventional [`clean` target](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Clean) because you want to ensure that all built files are deleted without having to put conditional shell code around every single `rm` invocation.

[`DEL`](http://ss64.com/nt/del.html) has an `/F` flag which causes `DEL` to go ahead and delete files for which you do not have write permission. However, it will still complain if you try to remove a nonexistent file (unlike `rm -f`):

```
C:\Users\binki>DEL /F nonexistent
Could Not Find C:\Users\binki\nonexistent

C:\Users\binki>rm -f nonexistent

C:\Users\binki>
```

Maybe there is a better way, but I think `rm -f`’s behavior can only be replicated with the help of [`IF EXIST`](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html). Thus, I propose `IF EXIST <filename> DEL /F <filename>` to be the closest available [`cmd`](http://ss64.com/nt/) syntax to replicate the behavior of `rm -f <filename>`:

```
C:\Users\binki>IF EXIST nonexistent DEL /F nonexistent

C:\Users\binki>touch existent& chmod u-w existent

C:\Users\binki>DEL existent
C:\Users\binki\existent
Access is denied.

C:\Users\binki>IF EXIST existent DEL /F existent

C:\Users\binki>ls -l existent
ls: existent: No such file or directory

C:\Users\binki>
```

Answer (score 0):

rm -f forces the delete of a file. IF you need to delete everything in a specific folder, including folders withing folders, you would need to do rm -rf in unix.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel comfortable with UNIX commands, you can use a UNIX command shell simulator in windows, the one that I use is called CYGWIN:

http://www.cygwin.com/